# Power Kernel Error

Tags: windows-10, crash, power

When I am trying to to heavy tasks (like gaming) on my machine it crashes randomly. When this happens the screen goes black and PC shuts down, after 5 sec it powers on again (even if I disable the option to power on right after a crash).
When I look into my event log it shows me the Power Kernel Error id:41.
I already tried a few fixes to fix this problem:

*I checked my RAM if it is corrupt: it is not*
*I send my PSU for repair: PSU is just working fine*
*I am monitoring my tempetures: nothing is getting extremly hot*

Can somone help me out to find a solution or to fix this problem?
Thank you

Here are some of my specs:
PSU: Intel i5-4440
GPU: Asus RX480 OC
PSU: CoolerMaster G650M
SSD: Samsung 850 EVO 250GB
RAM: Crucial Ballistix Sport XT 8GB
MOBO: AsRock H81M-HDS

Error Log I Get:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>6</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-11-23T15:17:59.731559400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>8807</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-86LB924</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">80</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0xfffff80f00000450</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0xfffff80f27117b36</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x2</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">true</Data> 
  <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

P.S If I forgot something, I will add it.

Comment: Are you over-clocking? If so, try running at default speeds. Also, if the 8GB RAM is on two cards, try swapping them.

Comment: My CPU is not really for overclocking, so never tried it. Already have swaped the RAM sticks.

Comment: OK. Nothing else that's obvious. Have you checked the event logs to see what sort of shut-down / restart you are experiencing (full restart / hibernate / sleep)?

Comment: I will add log in post. DONE

Comment: It looks more like a power blip than a kernel crash, though the PSU looks as though it ought to be adequate. Some BIOS firmware supports reboot after power failure, and it may be this which is causing the restart, regardless of the OS "restart after crash" setting. But I'm not really an expert in this area: I've just been asking the questions I would ask myself if I experienced this. Thinking "out of the box", is there a chance that there is a poor mains lead connection (not pushed fully home in the socket at either end), or maybe on one of the internal cables? Vibration could interrupt power.

Comment: [you get a BSOD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x50--page-fault-in-nonpaged-area), so [analyze the dump with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)

Comment: Point is: I tried a few things to make sure that Windows is creating a dump file after a crash. But it doesnt create one. I think the system does not even have enough time to create one when it crashes. Point is I DONT get BSOD. The system just shuts down without any warning.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I dont get a BSOD, BSOD stands for: Blue Screen of Death. My pc gets a black screen, becaus it just shuts down out of the blue.

Comment: BSOD = Bugcheck and I see that you get one (BugcheckCode 80 = https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x50--page-fault-in-nonpaged-area)